# Line value in the chart is not working property

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to make a **line and stacked column chart** like this:

[image: Stacked column about departments]

The problem is that the values of my database doesn't match with the line 
values.

My chart have 2 levels in the hierarchy, one of Departments and another of 
Subdepartments. The line value is the objetive of each subdepartment and 
columns are the quatity of occupational accident by each subdepartment.

Considering this **I have 3 tables:**

1. **OPS**, this table contains the quantity of occupational accident
2. **DEPARTMENTS**, this table contains subdepartments and departments
3. **OBJETIVES**, this table contains the objetive by subdepartment (This table was created by myself in Excel)

   [image: Departments table]

This is my Departments table where **ID** is the subdepartmentID(as "Nombre" in my table) and **DepartamentoPadreID** is the Department that have another subdepartments. **E.G.**

*The ID 113 that is Petronor contains another departments as 114= Economico Financiera, 115= Fiabilidad y Mantenimiento and so on that's why departments 114 and 115 are subdepartments inside Petronor (113) and the subdepartment Economico Financiera(114) what is subdepartments from Petronor contains another departments.*

This is the relationship beetween my tables:

[image: RelationShip]

My Departments table is joined with OPS by the ID and it has many relations with OPS because we distinguish beetween

1. IDDepartment
2. ID from observed department
3. ID from observer department

The table below contains the objetive by each of subdepartment:

[image: Objetives table]

And this is my chart by subdepartments:

[image: Subdepartment's chart]

As you can see i didn't put any blank or null value in my table and my chart is taking blanks values.

Someone know what's the error? It's weird because i did the same with another 3 tables and i don't have any error.

Comment: Do you explicitly use the inactive relationships (dotted lines) in your model, if yes, how? Which one of the 5 between OPS en Departments is the active one?

Comment: The active relationship in OPS is DepartamentoID all the others are inactive relationships.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the two active relationships to consider are: **DepartamentoID to ID** for OPS to Departments, and **DepartObservadoNombre to Departemento** for OPS to OPSObjetivoADepartamento? If that is the case, can you show a part of your OPS table?